# How to save the results of a called method of all the objects in an array?

Tags: java

I am creating a program that handles a car dealership. The user has the opportunity to add a car in the store by creating a random 3 digit number.

Now the question is how I can search/delete cars depending on the 3 digit code?

I'm thinking that I need every code that the cars have to save it on an array so I can search and delete afterwards.

I have created a class and certain methods on it, I have also created 5 objects and I'm trying to see if it works on these 5.

Here is the method of the random number:

I use the metritis variable because I can't achieve to place correctly the values on the array so I have to give parameter of 1,2,3,4,5 so I can place them correctly to the array.

```
package antiprosopeia;
import java.util.Random;

public class Antiprosopeia {

    private String company,colour;
    private int model,horsePower,speed,price,specialCode,metritis;
    private int[] codes = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0}; 

    public Antiprosopeia(String company, String colour, int model, int horsePower, int speed, int price) {
        this.company = company;
        this.colour = colour;
        this.model = model;
        this.horsePower = horsePower;
        this.speed = speed; 
        this.price = price;  
    }

    public Antiprosopeia() {  
        company = "";  colour = "";  model = 0; horsePower = 0; speed = 0;          price = 0;   
    }


    public void setRandomNumber(int metritis) { 
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randNum2 = rand.nextInt(900) + 100;
        specialCode = randNum2;

        codes[metritis] = specialCode;
    }

    public void printarray() {
        for(int i=0; i<codes.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(" " + codes[i]);}
    }

    public void Info() {   
        System.out.println("Company : " + company + "\nColour : " + colour + "\nModel : " + model + "\nHorse Power : " + horsePower +
        "\nSpeed : " + speed + "\nPrice : " + price );   
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Antiprosopeia car1 = new Antiprosopeia("Toyota","red",333,100,2223,8000);
        car1.setRandomNumber(0); 

        Antiprosopeia car2 = new Antiprosopeia("Mercedes","yellow",233,100,2990,9000);
        car2.setRandomNumber(1);

        Antiprosopeia car3 = new Antiprosopeia("Volkswagen","green",153,100,2780,6000);
        car3.setRandomNumber(2);

        Antiprosopeia car4 = new Antiprosopeia("Mitsubisi","white",678,140,2600,7000);
        car4.setRandomNumber(3);

        Antiprosopeia car5 = new Antiprosopeia("Porsche","black",390,1000,2000,30000);
        car5.setRandomNumber(4);    
    }        
}
```

[EDIT] Now when i call the printarray() method it seems that at my array only one value is hold and all the others are zer0s as i defined the array at start of my program

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Hello, the problem is that when i call the printarray() method, it seems that in my array only 1 value is saved and the rest are 0 as i defined them at the start of my program

Comment: You can't just "remove" from an array. Searching should be straight-forward

Comment: i think that by remove it could mean that i will put at the array[i] = 0 or something like that, something that shows that no value of car is in there.

Comment: Please show us a [mcve] of your code. We cannot see how you initialized `codes`, or your main method for how you use these methods. Yes, `codes` initializes to all zeros when you make it a `new int[size]`

Comment: now about the search yes is straightforward by the time that i have all the values in my array, the problem is that i cant get all of them in the array as i wanted, something is wrong with my methods or i havent understand yet how classes and objects work

Comment: wait a moment to give you all the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were doing this, I would use a HashMap. This way you know that you have a unique 3 digit number, and if you wanted to, you could also store more data. You could do something like:

```
HashMap<Integer, Car> cars = new HashMap<Integer, Car>();
```

This example would allow you to add a car object to the map. You don't have to that, but it's an option. If you didn't want to do that, you could do:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> cars = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

and then do:

```
cars.put(123, "Description of car");
```

Using a HashMap would give you more options when storing the data. This would also prevent you from creating an array with 1000 elements, all of which are 0 until you have a value for them. You could easily print out all your numbers by doing:

```
for(int number : cars.entrySet()){
    System.out.println("My car number: " + number);
}
```

Searching for keys would extremely easy, as you could do:

```
String description = cars.getKey(123);
```

If `description` was null, you would know that there is no key for it.

Comment: Thank you verymuch. The truth is i didnt know how hastable works but now i will read on them and i will make this excersise work. amazing explanation thanks bro

Comment: My pleasure! Hashmaps are an extremely valuable data structure. I would definitely read up on them and learn about them. As you can see they are easy to use, and give you a lot of flexibility. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that each `Antiprosopeia` object has its *own* `codes` array. They are not shared.

If you really want each object to have a Random ID, then assign that within the constructor.

```
public class Antiprosopeia {

    private String company,colour;
    private int model,horsePower,speed,price,specialCode,metritis;
    private int randID;


    public Antiprosopeia(String company, String colour, int model, int horsePower, int speed, int price){
        this.company = company;
        this.colour = colour;
        this.model = model;
        this.horsePower = horsePower;
        this.speed = speed; 
        this.price = price; 
        this.randID = new Random().nextInt(900) + 100;
    }

    public Antiprosopeia(){  
        this("", "", 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public int getID() { return this.randID; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
         return String.format(
            "Company : %s\n" + 
            "Colour : %s\n" +
            "Model : %s\n" +
            "Horse Power : %d\n" +
            "Speed : %d\n" +
            "Price : %d\n", 
            company, colour, model, horsePower, speed, price 
        );
    }
```

If you want to print all those objects,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Antiprosopeia> cars = new ArrayList<Antiprosopeia>();

    cars.add(new Antiprosopeia("Toyota","red",333,100,2223,8000));
    cars.add(new Antiprosopeia("Mercedes","yellow",233,100,2990,9000));

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++) {
        Antiprosopeia c = cars.get(i);
        System.out.println(c.getID());
        System.out.println(c);
    } 

}
```